# Update tcolorbox package on Debian

Tags: packages, installing, debian

I am running Debian and I have installed `tex-live` successfully. I really need to upgrade my current version of `tcolorbox`, which is 1.30 to the latest. I have downloaded the zip file but I have no idea how to install it. Documentation included has not been so helpful. Can you please help me figure it out?

Comment: Follow the instructions on http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/3954

Comment: If you have installed a vanilla TeX Live, use the package manager to update (`tlmgr`), if you have used `apt-get` to install teX Live, use `apt-get` to update the (meta?)package.

Comment: @Johannes_B unfortunately tlmgr doesn't seem to be on my machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)